# Consuming REST service with SSO authentication

Tags: javascript, web-services, wcf, rest, authentication

There is a server from which I consume web services (https://example.com/zzzzzz/rest/services/)

If I just paste this in Chrome, I'm prompted to authenticate. I put my known credentials and them I'm free to roam around.

However, if I try to access something like :

https://example.com/zzzzzz/rest/services/tttttt/uuuuuu/MapServer

in Javascript with XMLHttpRequest, I get a 401 Unauthorized response every time. It works if I add a header to this request with my credentials:

```
xml_req.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "Basic " + btoa("username:password");
```

However, this would mean to expose that username and password in every JS code and also add a header to each XMLHttpRequest (which I cannot do at this point).
The above server is not mine, so I cannot do anything to it other than consume services after I login.

Is there a way I can get my own server (IIS) to handle this authentication for me whenever I try to access those services?

Extra info : This is all for an ArcGIS server.

Comment: This might help you, http://chrisroos.co.uk/blog/2013-03-08-the-behaviour-of-xmlhttprequest-withcredentials-when-used-with-cors

Comment: Hello, thanks for the reply! However it seems that in the end he still sets the request header and hardcodes the username/password (in base64).
I think I might have to somehow make a proxy server which forwards the requests and returns the results but also handles the authentication for me. However I'm not exactly sure how to do that...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution.
The idea is to create a webservice (ashx in my case) which gets the requested service to be proxied as a parameter (myproxy.com?https://websitetobeproxied.com/serviceToBeProxied), sends it to the proxied server along with the credentials (using network credentials), fetches the result and sends it back to the client.

This would be the http request function which passes the credentials :

```
    private System.Net.WebResponse doHTTPRequest(string uri, byte[] bytes, string method, string contentType, ServerUrl serverUrl) {

    System.Net.HttpWebRequest req = (System.Net.HttpWebRequest)System.Net.HttpWebRequest.Create(uri);
    req.ServicePoint.Expect100Continue = false;


    // Add credentials
     req.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("username", "password");

    //For testing I automatically validate any ssl certificates. You may want to disable this in production
    req.ServerCertificateValidationCallback += (sender, certificate, chain, sslPolicyErrors) => {
        return true; 
    };

    //Get the request method ("GET", "SET" etc.)
    req.Method = method;

    if (bytes != null && bytes.Length > 0 || method == "POST") {
        req.Method = "POST";
        req.ContentType = string.IsNullOrEmpty(contentType) ? "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" : contentType;
        if (bytes != null && bytes.Length > 0)
            req.ContentLength = bytes.Length;
        using (Stream outputStream = req.GetRequestStream()) {
            outputStream.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
        }
    }
    return req.GetResponse();
}
```

And this would be the method to fetch and send the result back :

```
    private bool fetchAndPassBackToClient(System.Net.WebResponse serverResponse, HttpResponse clientResponse, bool ignoreAuthenticationErrors)
{
    if (serverResponse != null)
    {
        clientResponse.ContentType = serverResponse.ContentType;
        using (Stream byteStream = serverResponse.GetResponseStream())
        {
            // Text 
            if (serverResponse.ContentType.Contains("text") ||
                serverResponse.ContentType.Contains("json") ||
                serverResponse.ContentType.Contains("xml"))
            {
                using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(byteStream))
                {
                    string strResponse = sr.ReadToEnd();
                    if (
                        !ignoreAuthenticationErrors
                        && strResponse.IndexOf("{\"error\":{") > -1
                        && (strResponse.IndexOf("\"code\":498") > -1 || strResponse.IndexOf("\"code\":499") > -1)
                    )
                        return true;
                    clientResponse.Write(strResponse);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                // Binary response (Image or other binary)
                // Don't cache the result
                clientResponse.CacheControl = "no-cache";
                byte[] buffer = new byte[32768];
                int read;
                while ((read = byteStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
                {
                    clientResponse.OutputStream.Write(buffer, 0, read);
                }
                clientResponse.OutputStream.Close();
            }
            serverResponse.Close();
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```